# How to execute jar internally or from dependency within application that is running?

Tags: java, maven, jar, dependencies, virtual-machine

I have code which works that will install third party library into my application, but I'm using path to jar from my desktop. This is not intended to operate from my local machine.

How to get this path from dependency (this library is included through the pom.xml).
Some maven plugin for that? To replace with my hardcoded string? Best practices?

MyApp.class

```
String jarPath = "/home/Desktop/some-jar.jar"; //this is a problem

String pid = getPid();
logger.info("Attaching to target JVM with PID: " + pid);
VirtualMachine jvm = VirtualMachine.attach(pid);

jvm.loadAgent(jarPath);  // path goes to loadAagent
vm.detach();
logger.info("Attached to target JVM and loaded Java agent successfully");
```

Main call

```
public static void main(String... args) {
   MyApp.run();
}
```

Console log:

```
[main] INFO  com.whatever.MyApp- Attaching to target JVM with PID: 14232 
some-jar installed
[main] INFO  com.whatever.MyApp- Attached to target JVM and loaded Java agent successfully
[main] INFO  Starting App...
```

Comment: It depends on how you packaging your application.

Comment: maven-install-plugin you can use to specify your  local jars to your packaging

Comment: @SivaKumar l have one "main.jar" and this new jar it's included inside him. How to get to him?
jar:file:main.jar!/included.jar does not work...